# Javabean in MVC and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I have a MVC project for a website in java.

I'm coding in Eclipse and i use Tomcat and derby database.

I have the following javabean:

```
package collaboration;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver;

public class Modello {



    private String tipoInfo;
        private String ur = "jdbc:derby:/Users/sample;create=true";
        private String us = "ciao";
        private String p = "ciao";

        public Modello(){
            this.tipoInfo = "sconosciuto";
        }

        public String getTipoInfo(){
            return this.tipoInfo;
        }

        public void setTipoInfo(String tipoInfo){
            this.tipoInfo = tipoInfo;
        }

        public String getCatalogo(){

            String risultato = null;

            try{

                DriverManager.registerDriver(new ClientDriver());
                Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(ur, us, p);
                PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("select titolo, autore, prezzo from libreria.libro");
                ResultSet controllo = statement.executeQuery();

                while(controllo.next()){
                    risultato += controllo.getString(1);
                }

                connect.close();

            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            return risultato;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Modello ciao = new Modello();
            System.out.println(ciao.getCatalogo());
        }

}
```

If i run separately this code as a java program it works with no problem. But if i use it as a javabean in a JSP page on a Tomcat server i get this issue: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:/Users/sample;create=true

This is the code i i use for the javabean in a JSP.

```
<%@page import="collaboration.Modello"%>
<jsp:useBean id="model" scope="page" class="collaboration.Modello" />
<jsp:setProperty name="model" property="*" />
<jsp:getProperty name="model" property="catalogo" />
```

What is the matter?

Comment: Have you put the derby jdbc jar in WEB-INF/lib folder for web application?

Comment: Yes i do, but it still doesn't work